# "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 JsonDecoder can't decode

Tags: swift, decode, jsondecoder

```
class NewsService {
    func fetchNews() throws -> [News] {
        let data = Data(JsonData.data1.utf8)
        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsResponse.self, from: data).data
        } catch  {
            print(error)
            throw error
        }
    }
}

struct JsonData {

  static let data0 = """
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "news_url": "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4523221-what-is-holding-back-china-stimulus",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/a/t/image-1316474363-1451807.jpg",
                "title": "What Is Holding Back China Stimulus?",
                "text": "One of the vexing questions for China watchers has been the lack of stimulus delivered, despite the maintenance of the government's 5.5% GDP target for 2022 (although there is skepticism around the ability to reach that 5.5%). One of the big challenges China faces relative to South Korea is the amount of debt it holds for the level of income.",
                "source_name": "Seeking Alpha",
                "date": "Thu, 14 Jul 2022 04:03:00 -0400",
                "topics": [
                    "paylimitwall"
                ],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Article"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.barrons.com/articles/wall-street-upbeat-growth-stocks-51657748829",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/n/m/m02d20210325t2i1556169604w940fhfwllplsqrlynxmpeh2o0wy-738702-1451796.jpg",
                "title": "Wall Street Chooses an Odd Time to Be Upbeat About Growth Stocks",
                "text": "Investors have slowly been trickling back toward growth stocks. But with interest rates creeping up and a recession increasingly likely, growth may still be under pressure.",
                "source_name": "Barrons",
                "date": "Thu, 14 Jul 2022 03:15:00 -0400",
                "topics": [
                    "paywall"
                ],
                "sentiment": "Neutral",
                "type": "Article"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4523213-why-good-news-is-good-news-even-if-it-makes-the-market-go-down",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/8/h/image-479607780-1451794.jpg",
                "title": "Why Good News Is Good News Even If It Makes The Market Go Down",
                "text": "Pundits often discuss bad news being good news and good news being bad news. They are referring to the phenomenon in which the market seems to move opposite the directionality of the news.",
                "source_name": "Seeking Alpha",
                "date": "Thu, 14 Jul 2022 03:09:17 -0400",
                "topics": [
                    "paylimitwall"
                ],
                "sentiment": "Positive",
                "type": "Article"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.foxbusiness.com/markets/nyse-senior-market-strategist-bad-inflation-data-what-means-future-fed-action",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/v/l/aada5a43-7eb4-4140-a66c-690c8fbaa0e8-1451762.jpeg",
                "title": "NYSE senior market strategist on 'bad' inflation data and what it means for future Fed action",
                "text": "New York Stock Exchange Senior Market Strategist Michael Reinking weighed in on the latest inflation data, warning that more aggressive action from the Fed should be expected.",
                "source_name": "Fox Business",
                "date": "Thu, 14 Jul 2022 00:15:39 -0400",
                "topics": [],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Article"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.cnbc.com/2022/07/14/copper-is-key-to-electric-vehicles-wind-and-solar-power-were-short-supply.html",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/1/0/104668861-rts1bcmp-copper-1451765.jpg",
                "title": "A coming copper shortage could derail the energy transition, report finds",
                "text": "Copper demand is set to soar as renewable energy like wind and solar become more popular. But there's one problem: We don't have enough.",
                "source_name": "CNBC",
                "date": "Thu, 14 Jul 2022 00:01:01 -0400",
                "topics": [],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Article"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.reuters.com/markets/us/dollar-resumes-relentless-rise-inflation-stokes-fed-bets-2022-07-14/",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/4/u/m02d20220714t2i1603941710w940fhfwllplsqrlynxmpei6d029-1451748.jpg",
                "title": "Dollar resumes relentless rise as inflation stokes Fed bets",
                "text": "The dollar resumed its relentless rise on Thursday, driven by both expectations for faster Federal Reserve policy tightening and safe-haven flows amid growing fears of a recession.",
                "source_name": "Reuters",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 23:11:00 -0400",
                "topics": [],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Article"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.cnbc.com/2022/07/14/copper-prices-are-signaling-investors-are-negative-on-the-economy-anz.html",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/z/g/107087883-1657684863189-gettyimages-1365773314-vcg111365682616-1451739.jpeg",
                "title": "Copper prices are signaling that investors are bearish on the economy, strategist says",
                "text": "Copper is seen as a leading indicator of economic health because of its use in many sectors.",
                "source_name": "CNBC",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 22:39:20 -0400",
                "topics": [],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Article"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4523174-strong-case-why-were-now-in-a-recession",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/d/t/image-482367896-1451726.jpg",
                "title": "A Strong Case Why We Are Now Likely In A Recession",
                "text": "One perspective on Real GDP growth is simply aggregate hours worked X the output per hour worked. Aggregate hours worked in the economy is peaking, per capita has already peaked.",
                "source_name": "Seeking Alpha",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 21:40:25 -0400",
                "topics": [
                    "paylimitwall"
                ],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Article"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BG-uuwxHdv0",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/0/p/0pljj-1451707.jpg",
                "title": "Federal Reserve's Mester on Inflation, Interest Rates (Full Interview)",
                "text": "Federal Reserve Bank of Cleveland President Loretta Mester discusses the central bank's efforts to cool inflation. US inflation hit a four-decade high last month, likely strengthening the Fed's resolve to aggressively raise interest rates.",
                "source_name": "Bloomberg Markets and Finance",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 20:47:06 -0400",
                "topics": [],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Video"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://invezz.com/news/2022/07/14/inflation-soars-9-1-but-attention-could-turn-to-supply-side-a-deep-dive/",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/g/i/girl-at-gas-station-1451703.jpg",
                "title": "Inflation soars 9.1% but attention could turn to supply-side – A Deep Dive",
                "text": "In what has become (almost) commonplace, the US CPI headed higher once again, galloping to 9.1% on an annual basis in June and registering a 41-year high. The latest inflation print outdid both May's reading of 8.6% and the Dow Jones' forecast of 8.8%.",
                "source_name": "Invezz",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 20:47:00 -0400",
                "topics": [],
                "sentiment": "Neutral",
                "type": "Article"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.cnn.com/2022/07/13/business/nightcap-inflation-cpi-fed/index.html",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/q/6/220713160243-12-jerome-powell-0615-super-169-1451701.jpg",
                "title": "The Fed has few options as inflation runs hot",
                "text": "Editor's Note: This story is part of CNN Business' Nightcap newsletter. To get it in your inbox, sign up for free, here.",
                "source_name": "CNN Business",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 20:38:33 -0400",
                "topics": [],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Article"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dt055-KPWFg",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/m/q/watch-jim-cramer-break-down-charts-analysis-from-carley-garner-1451685.jpg",
                "title": "Watch Jim Cramer break down charts analysis from Carley Garner",
                "text": "The \"Mad Money\" host broke down fresh charts analysis from DeCarley Trading's Carley Garner on Wednesday's episode of the show.",
                "source_name": "CNBC Television",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 20:31:35 -0400",
                "topics": [
                    "cramer"
                ],
                "sentiment": "Neutral",
                "type": "Video"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.marketwatch.com/story/feds-mester-says-inflation-data-uniformly-bad-but-not-ready-to-commit-to-even-bigger-rate-hike-11657757421",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/q/m/im-465468size1777777777777778width800-1451682.jpg",
                "title": "Fed's Mester says inflation data ‘uniformly bad,' but not ready to commit to even bigger rate hike",
                "text": "Federal Reserve Bank of Cleveland President Loretta Mester said inflation data released earlier Wednesday was terrible, but she wasn't yet ready to commit to further accelerating central bank interest rate rises to deal with the problem.",
                "source_name": "Market Watch",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 20:10:00 -0400",
                "topics": [
                    "paylimitwall"
                ],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Article"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WS7Rx5yaZno",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/m/q/us-will-see-a-recession-if-this-happens-steve-moore-1451690.jpg",
                "title": "US will see a recession if this happens: Steve Moore",
                "text": "Committee to Unleash Prosperity's Steve Moore and Texas Republican Rep. Kevin Brady voice their concerns over the Build Back Better bill as Americans see record-high inflation on 'Kudlow.",
                "source_name": "Fox Business",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 20:00:08 -0400",
                "topics": [],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Video"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DM61ZDLhmZs",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/m/q/federal-reserves-mester-cpi-data-gives-no-reason-for-smaller-hike-1451679.jpg",
                "title": "Federal Reserve's Mester: CPI Data Gives No Reason for Smaller Hike",
                "text": "Federal Reserve Bank of Cleveland President Loretta Mester says the latest inflation report suggested the central bank should raise rates by at least 75 basis points later this month. US inflation hit a four-decade high in June.",
                "source_name": "Bloomberg Markets and Finance",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 19:50:25 -0400",
                "topics": [],
                "sentiment": "Neutral",
                "type": "Video"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zkTRAyfObxk",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/m/q/sofis-liz-young-outlook-on-inflation-earnings-1451663.jpg",
                "title": "SoFi's Liz Young Outlook on Inflation, Earnings",
                "text": "SoFi's Head of Investment Strategy Liz Young speaks with Emily Chang about her expectations for earnings this quarter, the CPI print, and her outlook on a potential recession.",
                "source_name": "Bloomberg Technology",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 19:43:40 -0400",
                "topics": [
                    "earnings"
                ],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Video"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPTiWjSzZP4",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/v/c/jim-cramer-explains-why-he-believes-the-fed-is-winning-its-battle-against-inflation-1451657.jpg",
                "title": "Jim Cramer explains why he believes the Fed is winning its battle against inflation",
                "text": "CNBC's Jim Cramer gave his thoughts on why he believes the Fed is succeeding in its efforts to tamp down inflation despite June's hotter than expected inflation data on Wednesday's episode of \"Mad Money.\"",
                "source_name": "CNBC Television",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 19:34:48 -0400",
                "topics": [
                    "cramer",
                    "madmoney"
                ],
                "sentiment": "Positive",
                "type": "Video"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfjgT0BiRTk",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/k/8/charts-suggest-the-euro-could-see-a-swift-rally-and-lift-the-stock-market-with-it-says-jim-cramer-1451658.jpg",
                "title": "Charts suggest the euro could see a 'swift rally' and lift the stock market with it, says Jim Cramer",
                "text": "CNBC's Jim Cramer explained charts analysis from DeCarley Trading's Carley Garner on Wednesday's episode of \"Mad Money.\"",
                "source_name": "CNBC Television",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 19:34:00 -0400",
                "topics": [
                    "tanalysis",
                    "cramer",
                    "madmoney"
                ],
                "sentiment": "Neutral",
                "type": "Video"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZ7FnxZd4N4",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/m/q/inflation-is-red-hot-1451670.jpg",
                "title": "Inflation Is Red Hot",
                "text": "Join @tomkeene, @FerroTV & @lisaabramowicz1 for the conversations that power your day on Bloomberg TV, Bloomberg Radio & the Surveillance podcast: https://trib.al/Ym3TxyA -------- Follow Bloomberg for business news & analysis, up-to-the-minute market data, features, profiles and more: http://www.bloomberg.com Connect with us on... Twitter: https://twitter.com/business Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/bloombergbusiness Instagram: https://www.instagram.com/bloombergbusiness/",
                "source_name": "Bloomberg Markets and Finance",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 19:31:12 -0400",
                "topics": [],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Video"
            },
            {
                "news_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQLbJ3oPzjk",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/k/e/the-fed-is-winning-against-inflation-despite-red-hot-june-cpi-number-jim-cramer-says-1451650.jpg",
                "title": "The Fed is winning against inflation despite red-hot June CPI number, Jim Cramer says",
                "text": "The \"Mad Money\" host explained why he believes inflation has peaked in Wednesday's episode of the show.",
                "source_name": "CNBC Television",
                "date": "Wed, 13 Jul 2022 19:26:43 -0400",
                "topics": [
                    "cramer",
                    "madmoney"
                ],
                "sentiment": "Positive",
                "type": "Video"
            }
        ]
    }
    """


    static let data1 = """
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "news_url": "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4523221-what-is-holding-back-china-stimulus",
                "image_url": "https://cdn.snapi.dev/images/v1/a/t/image-1316474363-1451807.jpg",
                "title": "What Is Holding Back China Stimulus?",
                "text": "One of the vexing questions for China watchers has been the lack of stimulus delivered, despite the maintenance of the government's 5.5% GDP target for 2022 (although there is skepticism around the ability to reach that 5.5%). One of the big challenges China faces relative to South Korea is the amount of debt it holds for the level of income.",
                "source_name": "Seeking Alpha",
                "date": "Thu, 14 Jul 2022 04:03:00 -0400",
                "topics": [
                    "paylimitwall"
                ],
                "sentiment": "Negative",
                "type": "Article"
            }
        ]
    }
"""
}
struct NewsResponse: Decodable {
    let data: [News]
}

struct News: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    let newsURL: String
    let imageURL: String
    let title: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case newsURL = "news_url"
        case imageURL = "image_url"
        case title
    }
}
```

For context, I used two exact same json format string data (JsonData.data0 and JsonData.data1). JsonData.data1 could be decoded but data0 couldn't. The difference is the size. After converting string to data, data0's byte size is 15522. When data is over certain amount of byte, it seems that JsonDecoder can't decode data. If so, any way to solve this problem?? The title is the error message form xcode when I use data0 which is a large json string.

I hope you guys can help me. thank you!!!

Comment: as you said, the code you show works well with `data1`, show us the `data0`, the one that gives the error.

Comment: Usually code 3840 indicates a server error sent as HTML.

Comment: It means the json data you have received from the API it self not a valid json formate. So, just cross verify with your backing team once. Or else try with online rest client once and verify

Comment: show ```data0```

Comment: the error you get is not due to the size of the response. 15.5kb is not big.
 I've tested your code with 150kb, the JSONDecoder can easily cope with that. There must be something else that is different with `data0`. Maybe you need an optional var somewhere?

Comment: Use a page like jsonlint.com or a text editor that has json validation to check the received json.

Comment: as a test, try using `String?` for `newsURL`, `imageURL` and `title` in `News`. See if that works with `data0`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine  I added data0 which couldn't be decoded. i already tried making var optional but it din't work

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you. i used jsonlint.com and both of json data i used are valid.

Comment: @uditha i added data0

Comment: @JayachandraA i added data0.  this is valid json data according to jsonlint.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NewsResponse` and `News`, are valid structs. However
your `data0` has some escaped quotes in the `text` field,
such as `"text": "The \"Mad Money\" host explained ..."`

It is not a problem, if for example, you put `data0` in a file and read it and then decode it.
But when you use the `""" ... """` it is a problem.

So if you get the content of `data0` directly from an API, it should decode  without errors. But not if you use your `static let data0 = """..."""`

However you can use the following to keep the special characters:

```
  static let data0 = #"""   
   ..... 
   """#
```

and this should decode without errors. Works well for me.